# Is it possible to create multiple google cloud instances and upload files to and download files from all of them at once?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, automation

I just started using google cloud, I want to create 10 virtual machines and upload files to them to run various scripts.

I have been doing it manually one by one. Is it possible to automate creating the servers all at the same time?

I have already tried using managed instance groups, but they are always on and they scale automatically, I need to control them individually.

Also, can I use a tool to upload files to all of them at once and download all the files from them at the same time?

Comment: There are tools such as Bitvise that provide command line tools to transfer files in scripts. However, I am not aware of any tools to do this in parallel. The Google Cloud CLI also supports transferring files. You could write a script to automate transferring files. If you are a developer there are many libraries that support SSH/SFTP. Google search. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp  https://www.bitvise.com/files/guides/sftpc-v736-commands.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can automate creating VM's in a various ways;

1. Use [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance) (either installed locally or through Cloud Shell). You can choose between public images or [create custom image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images) to suit your needs. Or if you just need some minor changes use [startup scripts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) while creating a VM to install/configure your apps.
2. Use [Deployment Manager](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs) - create come templates of the VM's to deploy and with a single command have a number of them.

Both of solutions provide you with complete control over the parameters of VM's created. You can even upload (or download directly to the new VM's) files you need.

[Uploading the files to the VM's is also possible via gcloud utility](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files#transfergcloud) - you can create a script to upload any files to the VM's (basic shell scripting experience required).

Lastly - here you can read more about [storage colution available in GCP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks) - but I'm guessing you will be using persisten disks & [buckets](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#gcsbuckets). You can easily [connect a bucket to your VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/gcs-buckets), mount it as a filesystem or just copy files to/from your VM's.

Ultimately you can read here about [various ways of transferring files to the GCP instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files).